# Need RegExpr matching group of 8 containing, 2+ uppercase, 2+ lowercase and 1+ number

Tags: filter, spam

I am trying to create a spam filter using Regular Expressions that matches the following situation.

- There is a group of exactly 8 alphanumeric characters to be matched.
- It must contain 2 or more uppercase letters;
- AND it must contain 2 or more lowercase letters;
- AND it must contain 1 or more numbers.

So far, all I have been able to come up with is this:

```
(?i)[A-Za-z0-9]{8}
```

My code does match a mixed case group of 8, but does not force upper or lower case or specify how many times each type must occur. So, I couple it with other must-haves that are always present in the messages in question.

Here is a sample of the pattern I am trying to detect:

```
WbNDSk9e
```

This is part of a spam URL. Other groups I have seen follow the same pattern of at least 2 each UC and LC letters and 1 or more numbers and always have exactly 8 characters. I've seen no other characters or variations yet.

To my knowledge, the only switch I am able to use is to turn on Case Sensitivity, with (?i). Some of the other switches I have seen in some replies do not work in the program I use. Am I asking too much from a single line RegExpr rule?

I currently use RegEx Match to test my rules and my anti-spam program uses the same  engine.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z].*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d).{8}$
```

Broken down:

`(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])` forces at least 2 upper-case letters.

`(?=.*?[a-z].*?[a-z])` forces at least 2 lower-case letters.

`(?=.*?\d)` forces at least 1 digit.

The `^ ... $` caret and dollar force that it matches the whole string.

You don't want the `(?i)` flag because it will make it case-insensitive.